# Expand a list item in a listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

My requirement is, I have a city icon and name of the city in front of it. When I clicked on either of this, that particular row in the list view should expand and display the description of that city(which I get by parsing from a plist).

Can anybody let me know, how to handle this? Is it with the listView object?

[image]

Here, the description like "This is new york", "You are in greenwhich village" should appear only when I click on the image or text "Soho"

Thanks in advance